# How to use volley token Authenticator?

Tags: java, android, authentication, token, android-volley

I would like to know how to use the Authenticator class provided by android volley. 
1 How i can send the request to have a token?
2 How i can check whether a token is invalid?

I didn't find any explications about this in internet so i ask here

This is the class:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/4474bc11f64b2b274ca6db5a1e23e8c1d143d5fa/volley/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/Authenticator.java

Comment: Pls look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141711/asynchronous-account-authentication-with-volley) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400398/token-authentication-with-volley). Moreover, I think you should search carefully, many topics available

Comment: Ok, I've understand how to getAuthToken but which parameter I have to pass? response,account,authTokenType and option, how the have to be initializate?

Comment: I have not ever tried it yet. Sorry can't help!